# PDF error - removing overlapped objects

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm hand-rolling a PDF (don't ask why, it's a long story) and I am now trying to define a Form XObject.

The page I'm working in is 8.5" x 11", moves the origin to the bottom-left, and converts to 96 dpi, so there's a line right at the top:

```
0.75 0 0 0.75 0 791 cm
```

For testing purposes, I'm just using the sample from the PDF manual:

```
35 0 obj
<<
/Type/XObject /Subtype/Form /FormType 1 /Name/form1 /BBox [0 0 200 200] /Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0] /Length 184>>
stream
0.5 0.5 0.0 sc
0 0 m
0 200 l
200 200 l
200 0 l
f
endstream
endobj
```

When I draw this object:

```
q
1 0 0 1 8 -1043 cm
/form1 Do
Q
```

However, I get errors in Adobe Reader, and running the Acrobat PreFlight check tells me:

```
An error was encountered while removing overlapping objects
```

Is there any way to get better details on this error?

Comment: You could try a different PDF consumer, for two reasons. Firstly as you've discovered Acrobat's error reporting is, well, basic. Secondly Acrobat silently ignores many, many errors, only offering to 'save changes' when you close the file. Ghostscript will give more meaningful errors and warnings, I'm sure other consumers will too. And if you post the entire PDF file somewhere public then we could look at it and tell you what's wrong ;-)

Comment: Could you share the pdf in question? Currently this is pure guesswork.

Comment: I'll see if the company I'm doing this for (I'm a contractor) is OK with me sharing the document ... in the mean time, GhostScript says "File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged."  Is there a "verbose" option?

Comment: Is there any way I can share the PDF privately?  I'll be happy to share the answer if we find it ...

Comment: `1
1 0 0 1 8 -1043 cm` - seem to be 7 arguments here, when `cm` expects 6.

Comment: Sorry, stupid transcription error, that first '1' is a 'q'

Comment: Sample file uploaded to http://www.sc3.net/test.PDF, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most other readers give better diagnostics than Adobe Acrobat. `xpdf` for example:

```
Syntax Error (324732): Incorrect number of arguments in 'sc' command
Syntax Error (2083): Bad block header in flate stream
```

The `sc` error can be fixed by inserting a `/DeviceRGB cs` just before it. The number of arguments depends on the current color space, which presumably, should be RGB, but is currently something else.

The `Bad block header` error indicates that there's something wrong with the binary data at byte offset 2083, which is object `4 0 R`. Something you'll need to investigate and fix.

Also note, that the PDF Specification recommends, an end-of-line marker before the, `endstream`, which is not present here.

Comment: As the great philosopher Homer Simpson would say, Doh!  The fill rectangle was a test I put in, to figure out why the real stuff wasn't drawing, and then of course the rectangle color was the real problem.  Thanks for pointing me to these tools for checking PDFs for errors, they will be a great help!